# Where can I find and submit bug reports on Google's Chrome browser?

Tags: google-chrome, bug-tracking

It will be important for developers wanting to develop for the chrome browser to be able to review existing bugs (to avoid too much pulling-out of hair), and to add new ones (to improve the thing).  Yet I can't seem to find the bug tracking for this project.  It *is* open source, right?

Comment: ... or you can just open about:linux-splash page and get detailed instructions

Answer (score 149, accepted):

Google is calling it [Chromium](http://code.google.com/chromium/) on Google Code

The [Chromium Bug Reporting Page](http://dev.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines) is there and has the link to submit bugs listed. (Google Account Required)

[Here's a direct link](https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=ah&passive=true&continue=https://appengine.google.com/_ah/conflogin%3Fcontinue%3Dhttps://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/entryafterlogin) to the bug report form.

Comment: Does this also apply to the official build of Chrome? Or just it's open source version? I ask because, I'm having visual artifacts every so often and I'd like to submit a screen shot (to illustrate my point, in the post literal manner) with a bug report. It seems to have something to do with Adobe Flash and it's roll over content being perfected, but corrupting the area that it WOULD take up if I had scrolled over it.

Comment: If your problem is specific to the Google build of Chrome, you could use the built-in reporting at http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=2a2135b6f50fd524&hl=en . The issue you've described, sounds like its not specific to the official build, but to the actual chrome project, so it might benefit to have that reported in Chromium itself.

Comment: @MarkTomlin Report it to the Chromium bug tracker. The official build of Chrome is directly based on Chromium.

Comment: @JamesWilkins - Whoops, looks like the direct link had my (now expired) token. It should work correctly now.

Comment: Does this also apply to Chrome on mobile?

Answer (score 17):

Go to the wrench -> About Google Chrome -> report an issue. (accurate as of v19.0.1084.46)

Comment: ...no such option. (8.0.552.237 (Official Build 70801))

Comment: I see this option using the Beta Channel of Chrome (v13), very easy.

Comment: This option is available at Tools -> Report an issue.

Comment: Mostly end-users file bugs through there. If you have technical details and a reproduction of the bug, file it through crbug.com/new (which is equivalent to the accepted answer).

Answer (score 11):

This is the home page for the Code: http://code.google.com/chromium/

And here's more info: http://dev.chromium.org/getting-involved including the bug list

Answer (score 7):

Click the Chrome menu ([image: the Chrome menu]), then **Help > Report an issue...**.

Since Google Code has been [deprecated](http://google-opensource.blogspot.co.uk/2015/03/farewell-to-google-code.html), you can also go to [**`bugs.chromium.org`**](https://bugs.chromium.org/) in order to report new bugs and features or search for the existing one. The Chrome browser is under *chromium* category, so after logging-in, you can submit a new bug report by clicking *New issue* on the top-left corner and follow the wizard steps.

See: [Report a problem or send feedback on Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95315) at Chrome Help

Answer (score 4):

From the [Google Site](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?answer=95760&query=bug&topic=&type=)

1. Click the Page menu page menu.
2. Select Report a bug or broken website.
3. Choose an issue type from the drop-down menu. The web address of the webpage you're on is recorded automatically.
4. If possible, add key details in the 'Description' field, including steps to reproduce the issue you're experiencing.
5. Keep 'Send source of current page' and 'Send screenshot of current page' checkboxes selected.
6. Click the Send report button to report a Google Chrome bug.

I don't see any reference to public bug tracking...

Comment: This is no longer available in the newest version of Chrome, as the page menu has been removed.

Comment: It is, under Tools -> Report an issue

Comment: @Pioul  it's not under Help > report an issue

Answer (score 3):

The Google Code site for the Chrome project is available at:

http://code.google.com/chromium/

Facilities available allow you to:

File bug reports;

Join the Google group discussions;

Submit a patch;

Plus there are links to the development blog and a whole bunch of other useful stuff.

Answer (score 3):

See the [Issues tab](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list) on Chrome's Google Code page.

Answer (score 3):

The bug tracker is here:

> https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/

Some shortcuts:

- [crbug.com](https://crbug.com/)
- [crbug.com/new](https://crbug.com/new) (file a new bug)
- [crbug.com/150835](https://crbug.com/150835) (go to a bug by number)