# Chrome number field horizontal scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created a number field which has the text inside aligned to the right.

**UseCase:**

If you select the full text **or** when you use your middle mouse button inside of the input field to scroll I noticed that **it is possible to scroll the text for about 1px** to the left. So far I could only provoke this behavior **in Chrome**.

You can see it in action with this code:

```html
<input type="number" value="15" style="text-align: right;" />
```

**Solution:**

I could probably disable the scrolling on the element but I wanted to ask you **if there is an elegant way to fix this**.

Here you can see the code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mEmAvz

Comment: All I can do is confirm that this happens in Chromium as well, and exclusively, as far as I can tell. It appears to be simply a glitch with Chromium's implementation of the number increase/decrease buttons. I played with a few settings really quick, but no dice.

Comment: @makshh Thank you for your response! The person in this thread wanted to disable the change of the number which occured when the field is scrolled. I have just a visual problem in which the number is offset by a few Pixel when the text is selected / the middlemouse button is pushed.

Comment: And this happens only with `text-align: right`?

Comment: This is correct! And so far this only happens in chrome.

Comment: It happens too on `type=text`. Textarea is OK.

Comment: Since this is reproducible it seems appropriate to [report it as a bug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40703/where-can-i-find-and-submit-bug-reports-on-googles-chrome-browser).

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce it on my chrome. Am I missing something here?

Comment: I confirm the issue on Chrome 51.0.2704.103 (64-bit)

Comment: I added an [issue (bug report)](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=625631) in the Chrome Issue Tracker, as @GeraldSchneider proposed. You can follow it with the [link](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=625631).

Comment: I can also reproduce the issue, the problem comes when aligning the text to the right, in my case using 51.0.2704.103 (64-bit)

Comment: Maybe it's a problem with the box model and you could try box-sizing:content-box;

Answer (score 1):

You could use text-indent with calc. Like so:

```
html {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
 box-sizing: inherit;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
  text-indent: calc(100% - 1.5em);
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/VilleKoo/u2ead3gz/1/

Comment: Try to write something like "999999" and unfocus.

Answer (score -2):

I did not understand exactly what you want, but I think so
`<input type="number" style="text-indent: calc(100% - 1.5em);" />`