# Chrome 53 Helper crashes (OSX)

Tags: angularjs, macos, google-chrome

I'm part of a web development team that is building websites using the Angular (1.x) framework. After a recent update to from Chrome 52 to Chrome 53, we've noticed one of our sites to become unresponsive.

The site in question is: https://www.slimnaarantwerpen.be/nl

The tab will become unresponsive when you resize the page (scale down, then scale back up) or when you toggle some of the map layers. (For example: Taxi) The Dev-tools are also unresponsive, so I'm unable to debug this issue...

This behaviour only occurs on Chrome 53.x.x on OSX. I've tested the above on Chrome 53.x.x on Windows and everything runs smoothly. Safari and Firefox also don't cause issues.

I can also confirm that this site runs correctly on Chrome 52.x.x, as I've run the site on that browser before updating to Chrome 53.x.x. I also used several testing laptops using 52 to confirm it's working, only to update them to 53 and notice the issue...

Does anyone have an idea if this is a common Chrome 53 issue? I read that changed some things under the hood to improve performance. What's the best way to contact Google regarding this issue?

Comment: for bug reports see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40703/where-can-i-find-and-submit-bug-reports-on-googles-chrome-browser

Comment: Thanks for this. :-)

Answer (score 6):

The problem was that an element inside an `ng-if` had `overflow: scroll` in combination with `height: 100%` applied to it. Apparently, Chrome 53 (OSX) does not like that...

Removing either and changing the styling resolved this issue.

I hope they fix this soon, but in the meantime I hope this answer can help anyone who has a similar problem. :-)

EDIT: This issue also seems to be OSX 10.11-specific, as this does not happen on OSX 10.10.x

Comment: Did you find an issue at crbug.com? If not, did you create one? Without a reported issue, the chances of it being fixed are significantly reduced.