# Chrome Issue: new Date() returning the time without timezone, but just the offset in Windows 7 OS

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

new Date() is returning the time without timezone, but just the offset in Windows 7 OS for chrome version **71.0.3578.80.**

Open console by pressing f12 and issue the new Date() in the JS console.

Windows 10: new Date() displays Mon Dec 10 2018 16:11:23 GMT-0500 **(Eastern Standard Time)**

Windows 7: new Date() displays Mon Dec 10 2018 12:27:23 GMT-0500 **(GMT-05:00)**

In Windows 10 it works fine. In windows 7 it is not showing Eastern Standard Time anymore. It used to be fine in both Windows 7 and 10 before chrome released their update.

Reading the release notes of the latest version has a point related to a modification for the relative times.

**Displaying relative times is now part of the Intl API**

I suspect the above change is breaking the time zone information in Windows 7.

Comment: Sounds like a perfect question to Jon.

Comment: @Alex Can you route or tag him here?

Comment: No, you can't ping users like that.

Comment: @Alex Got it.. So Is there any other way the developers can be made aware of this issue?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40703/where-can-i-find-and-submit-bug-reports-on-googles-chrome-browser)